# Vertical Align Span to A

Tags: css

I am trying to style an Input of type File:
http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/njAgJ

The HTML markup I am using is the following:

```
<span class="file">
  <a href="#">browse<input type="file" name="annex"/></a>                 
  <span>path</span>
</span>
```

The inner span (in RED) is to display the selected file (using JQuery).

The problem is I am not able to vertically align the RED span with the Browse "Button".

I tried other options but I always end with some kind of problem.

Could someone, please, help me out?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: What do you mean by vertically align? Do you want the bottoms to align? The tops to align? The text to align? Maybe a picture demonstrating what you are trying to achieve will help us understand your problem.

Comment: Hello, I want the text to align ... Just like this: codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/wIBdn. The problem with this is when using display: table-cell it makes the browse window to open where ever I click on the page and not only on the browse button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:table-cell` for both the `<a>` and the `<span>`.

Comment: You solution has a problem: now I am able to click any where as I was clicking on the browse button: http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/wIBdn. I tried your approach before but that was the problem I got.